# Solving box-constrained least-squares

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a linear least squares problem with linear constraints:

$$\min_x \| A x - b \|^2 \quad\text{subject to}\quad k_1 \leq x_i \leq k_2$$

Should quadratic programming be used here? If so, what would the formulation be?

Answer (score 1):

What should be used may depend on what software you are using.  Maple has a command **LSSolve** in its **Optimization** package to handle least-squares problems, including linearly-constrained ones.  It uses an active-set method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a fit case for the Matlab [function](http://www.mathworks.in/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) `lsqlin`. One of the dangers of quadratic programming in this case is that if your matrix $A$ is ill-conditioned, then quadratic programming leads to the formation of $A^T A$ in the cost function, whose condition number is even worse (squared).

Answer (score 0):

You can either solve it by a special solver (As noted by other answers) or use Gradient Descent where each iteration you project the solution onto the box of the constraints.

It will be something like that:

$$
\begin{align*}
{x}^{k + 1} & = {x}^{k} - \alpha ( {A}^{T} \left( A {x}^{k} - b \right) \\
{x}^{k + 2} & = \max \left\{ \min \left\{ {x}^{k + 1}, {k}_{2} \right\}, {k}_{1} \right\}
\end{align*}
$$

Where $ \alpha $ is the step size in the Gradient Descent.

Comment: Do you have an explanation or reference for why the max(min()) operator is a good idea?

Comment: Because it is the projection on the set of constraints. So it is not a _good idea_, it is the _optimal idea_.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with optimization, but I think I can think of a counter example. Imagine an objective function shaped like W, such that the left and right ends are higher than the middle part, but also outside the bounded region. So finding the left end or the right end and then projecting onto the bounded region gives a suboptimal solution, which is in the middle of the region. Is this incorrect?

Comment: The set $ \mathcal{S} = \left\{ \boldsymbol{x} \mid {k}_{1} \leq {x}_{i} \leq {k}_{2} \forall i \right\} $ is a convex function and the projection _onto that set_ is given by the above. You won't find a counter example for that as it is a simple projection problem solved in any book on convex optimization.